# Efficiently apply function to neuron outputs then sum, not apply function to sum

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to apply a nonlinearity to a neuron's individual inputs and sum the result, not sum the individual inputs and apply a nonlinearity. My current implementation is slow.

I have an input layer of size D, and the batch size is B. The next layer is `N` neurons wide, so the weight matrix `W = D x N`. Call my nonlinearity `f`.

In symbols, for neuron n, I want `f(w_{1n}x_1) + ... + f(w_{Dn}x_D)` instead of, as we normally have, `f(w_{1n}x_1 + ... + w_{Dn}x_D)`.

My vectorization of this process is slow. Currently, it exploits broadcasting, and I am wondering if there is a faster way to get what I want.

```
train = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(B, D, 1))
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([D, N]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([N]))

h1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.relu(tf.mul(train, w1)), 1) + b1
h1 = tf.reshape(h1, [B, N, 1])
```

I then proceed to feed this to the next layer. Doing this several times is  slow. I am wondering if there is some way I can make this more efficient or compute this differently.

Comment: What you've written should be fast, though I'm confused about what you're actually trying to accomplish by losing all of the intermediate state and just propagating N copies of the sum out to the next layer.  Can you elaborate on 'is slow'?  CPU or GPU?

Comment: For a toy 3-layer NN, 1000 forward passes with a ReLU is 10 seconds (CPU). For this set up, it's 5 minutes, provided it does not run into memory problems. N copies are not passed forward--each value in the BxNx1 tensor can be different. I intend to apply a different nonlinearity to the intermediate values, but I chose a ReLU for the post because it is not distracting.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're doing now - sorry, slow brain day.  Working on a real answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just to sanity check that we're on the same page:  A way of restating what you're asking for is to be able to apply a function f(x) to each scalar element*element product inside a matrix multiply, *before* those products are summed to produce the final output value.)

An unsatisfying - and perhaps someone can prove me wrong - answer is that I think it's the best you can do without writing a kernel to implement it.  The core challenge is that without a custom kernel (or implementing a block-decomposed matrix multiply out of raw ops, which sounds unpleasant), I can't think of a way to get the cache locality that you need to make this operation fast.